Copying a specific 70GB directory from a backup makes the system crash while it is not crashing when copying other directories on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I want to copy a 70GB directory from an exFat external hard drive formatted on a MacOS system to the internal harddrive of a linux Ubuntu LTS 24.04 system. Each time that I tried to transfer the file (either with rsync or cp the entire linux system crashes in the sense that the computer stops responding, the screen is frozen so that I have to hard reboot it by pressing the power button. I did not have problems when transfering other directories from the backup. In the culprit directory, there are approximately 411567 directories and files (using tree subdir > out and counting the line of out. This directory is containing many picture and code (it countains notes and exercices for image recognition deep learning algorithm.)
How is it possible to narrow down the search to the cuplrit file from that 70GB directory?
(This is the follow up of a very long question there: Copying files (cp and rsync) from rom MacOS formatted exFat sytematically crashes entire system (Ubuntu LTS 24.04) which I didn't delete as it contains many step upstream from the current situation). If a moderator thinks that I should delete one of the two question, I would thenk like to delete the previous one and keep the current one
Here is the output of $sudo journalctl  -b -1 -ex (however the crash happened at 01:47:34 and I don't see any particular warning signs, do you?)
May 11 01:44:08 mylenovo-ThinkPad-P1-Gen-6 systemd[2739]: launchpadlib-cache-clean.service - Clean up old files in the Lau>
░░ Subject: A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 786.
May 11 01:45:01 mylenovo-ThinkPad-P1-Gen-6 CRON[5609]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root>
May 11 01:45:01 mylenovo-ThinkPad-P1-Gen-6 CRON[5610]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
May 11 01:45:01 mylenovo-ThinkPad-P1-Gen-6 CRON[5609]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
May 11 01:46:05 mylenovo-ThinkPad-P1-Gen-6 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2892]: (EE) event5  - ELAN0686:00 04F3:320D Touchpad>
May 11 01:46:05 mylenovo-ThinkPad-P1-Gen-6 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2892]: See https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/>
May 11 01:46:06 mylenovo-ThinkPad-P1-Gen-6 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2892]: (EE) event5  - ELAN0686:00 04F3:320D Touchpad>
May 11 01:46:06 mylenovo-ThinkPad-P1-Gen-6 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2892]: See https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/>
May 11 01:46:17 mylenovo-ThinkPad-P1-Gen-6 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2892]: (EE) event5  - ELAN0686:00 04F3:320D Touchpad>
May 11 01:46:17 mylenovo-ThinkPad-P1-Gen-6 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2892]: See https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/>
May 11 01:46:17 mylenovo-ThinkPad-P1-Gen-6 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2892]: (EE) event5  - ELAN0686:00 04F3:320D Touchpad>
May 11 01:46:17 mylenovo-ThinkPad-P1-Gen-6 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2892]: See https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/>
May 11 01:46:35 mylenovo-ThinkPad-P1-Gen-6 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2892]: (EE) event5  - ELAN0686:00 04F3:320D Touchpad>
May 11 01:46:35 mylenovo-ThinkPad-P1-Gen-6 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2892]: See https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/>
May 11 01:46:35 mylenovo-ThinkPad-P1-Gen-6 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2892]: (EE) event5  - ELAN0686:00 04F3:320D Touchpad>

There was no problem of memory as shown with the free a few seconds before the crash:
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        32515972     3066244    19160136      730976    11487144    29449728
Swap:        8388604           0     8388604

EDITS

Maneuver 1

I ran the command tar cvf /dev/null /medial/mylenovo/bckp 2>&1 > temp_tarout. The process ended without any crash and there was no error that I could find in tarout.

Maneuver 2

I ran the following command:
# name of the file: script1
#!/bin/zsh
dest="$HOME/blah/blah"
src="/path/to/90GB/dir"

find $src -type f -print0 | \
  xargs -0 -r cp -t  $dest

saved the output into the file with zsh script1 >out1 and it crash during the run of the command
# name of the file: script2
#!/bin/zsh
dest="$HOME/blah/blah"
src="/path/to/90GB/dir"
  
find $src -type f -print0 | \
  xargs -0 -r cp -t --no-clobber $dest

saved the output into the file with zsh script1 >out2 but got the following error message:
cp: target directory '--no-clobber': No such file or directory
cp: target directory '--no-clobber': No such file or directory
cp: target directory '--no-clobber': No such file or directory
cp: target directory '--no-clobber': No such file or directory


Maneuver 3

I copied with rsync the incriminated directory from one hard drive to another hard drive, connected to the computer with Ubuntu 24.04. The problem persisted: it crashed again

Maneuver 4
Disabling the swap with the following command did not solve the problem:

sudo swapoff -a


You should eliminate the source media/filesystem as the source of the crash.  This will read every file on the device and not write anything: tar cvf /dev/null /my/mount/point.  Keep an eye on the filenames being printed as they're read, and see whether it's always the same one causing the crash.  If you don't observe any crashes when reading the files, the remaining candidates are: 1) your RAM is flaky, 2) your filesystem is corrupt, 3) your destination device has a hardware error.  //  If you can, switch to a text console during copy and video any kernel messages before the crash.

[Can't edit comments after five minutes.] I forgot: mount the exFAT read-only (be paranoid).

Klode has excellent suggestions. If you prefer a gui approach, try using the Double Commander app. It will tell you, during copy, when you have problem with either source or destination, and give options like skip... hopefully before any crash. It might help you to hone in to the actual problem.

Many thanks for your comment @robgrune Is Double Commander to be installed if you can monitor that from a different computer? Sorry but I am not sure to understand what would be the configuration with Double Commander

Many thanks for your comment and your help @klode So just to be sure that I am doing exactly what you suggested: I fist mounted the hard drive in read only using the following: sudo mount /dev/sda2 /media/mylenovo/bckp -o ro, I am going to do the following: tar cvf /dev/null /media/mylenovo/bckp > tarout and monitor what is happening in tarout, correct? Regarding the console, I am really not sure what you mean. Do you mean monitoring what is happening from another computer? If yes how concretely shall I do it?

I should have asked: by "crash" do you mean that 1) the copy fails, or 2) your desktop disappears and you see the login screen again, or 3) that your system reboots, or 4) it simply stops responding?  Double Commander will read and write, so isn't useful to test only the backup device/filesystem.  // Don't bother with > tarout for  failures 2 or 3.  If 1 or 4, add 2>&1 > tarout, to capture error messages too. // For the console, press eg.  to see console 2.  ( to return).  If failures 2, 3, 4, kernel error messages will appear directly there; no need to log in.

Many thanks for your comment @klode . So the crash I am referring to is 4): the entire computer stops responding, the screen is frozen. I ran the command tar cvf /dev/null /medial/mylenovo/bckp 2>&1 > temp_tarout. The process ended without any crash and there was no error that I could find in tarout`. I installed Double Commander open it but I am still not sure how I should use in my particular case. would there be a command line alternative maybe? Regardless of the last point, do you have an idea of a reasonable next step

The next step is to try writing to a different device that your desired destination.  If you get a crash, either the second destination device is also bad (unlikely), or your RAM may be flaky (more likely).  //  If no hang when writing to the different destination, re-try the copy operation that leads to the problem, but switch to a text console, watch for (and maybe video record) any kernel error messages that appear, and see whether the system hangs.  Let me know how you fare.

@klode Many thanks for your comment. So if I understood correctly, what I am going to do is the following: first I am going to try to copy the content of that directory to another HDD. If I get a crash, I'll assume that the RAM is flaky. In that case I'll have to use memtest (https://www.memtest86.com/) to make the diagnosis correct? Second, regarding the text console, do you mean Double Commander? or something else? Is something like a terminal within your computer which wouldn't be affected by the crash? Do you know maybe a tutorial for this particular maneuver?

Correct re: memtest86 or similar. // Though I forgot to mention that you should do a filesystem consistency check on the destination (to see whether the FS is corrupted).  // The keystrokes that I mentioned three comments above your most recent one "..." will do.  // Comments are too short and poorly formatted, so I didn't mention: the point here is to see any kernel messages that might appear just before your system hangs (kernel message are emitted directly to text consoles).  Messing about with tail might not show messages that appear instants before a hang.

@klode ok many thanks. I'll try to implement that and post the progress as soon as I can

Your notes indicate to me a hardware fault. I would firstly test all disk drives using testdisk. Obviously, if all tests pass, your problems lie within your system, To install testdisk... sudo apt install testdisk.  To verify install... sudo dpkg -l testdisk.  To run in terminal, enter testdisk. Follow the text-based menus.  Hope this helps you to discover the problem.

Your system shouldn't crash. After your system comes up, use sudo journalctl  -b -1 -ex to look at the messages just before the crash.
Do you have enough swap space to avoid the OOM-killer? free will show.
A solution:
#!/bin/bash
dest="$HOME/blah/blah"
src="/path/to/90GB/dir"
  
find $src -type f -print0 | \
  xargs -0 -r cp -t --no-clobber $dest

This will copy the files one at at time, add the -v option to cp to see each copy.I later added the --no-clobber, on case it was run multiple times. -

Thank you for your answer @waltinator . I ran your script twice. It crashed twice but the files that were copied at the time of the crash were not the same. I inserted the content of sudo journalctl -b -1 -ex at the time of the crash but did not see anything special. There was no problem of memory as the free command showed. What do you think?

You have posted a picture of a scrollable window, and truncated several important messages. Please replace it with a copy and paste of the text, and use the {} formatting tool. Please [edit] your question to reply. Do not use Add Comment

I asked about free to see if you have swap. Of course your memory is OK now. Please [edit] your Question and show us free and its result. "OK" doesn't help the diagnosis - you're not the expert, are you?

Thank you @waltinator for your comment. I tried the script you proposed but got an error message. I copied it in the edited question. Regarding the truncation of several important messages, do you mean that I truncated the message output with sudo journalctl -b -1 -ex? If this is the case, the problem is that the message output is 4000+ lines long and would not fit in the edited question. Or do you mean something else?

With respect to free, do you want an output of free at the time of the crash? If yes, the problem is that as the computer completely stops responding, I cannot have the output of that command at the time of the crash. Otherwise an idea would be to integrate a command that continuously print the output of free into a file. Is this what you mean? If no, what do you want me to try?

I had the same problem when upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04 on a new machine. Transferring data from an external drive (200GB+) kept freezing the system to the point I had to do a hard reset (mouse not moving, keyboard not responding). I noticed it to be an OOM error, but I'm on a 64GB ram machine. This shouldn't be happening.
Tried increasing and decreasing swap and vm.min_free_kbytes
Eventually disabling the swap is what fixed it:
sudo swapoff -a

Many thanks for your answer. Feels a little better to know that I am not alone in that situation. Unfortunately, I tried your solution twice, but the problem persisted despited disabling the swap with your command :(. Do you have any other ideas?

Too bad that didn't help :(. Besides disabling swap, I also added vm.min_free_kbytes = 1024000 to /etc/sysctl.conf, then run sysctl -p (this keeps 1GB memory free for kernel processes that really need it when the rest is full. This may not be a good idea if you only have 4GB of ram or so). I also used  DoubleCommander to transfer the files as someone mentioned above + I didn't touch my machine during the transfer not wanting any other process to eat up ram. None of those things solved the problem by themselves, but it may have been the combination.

If that doesn't work, maybe actually increasing the size of your swap could be another solution? Check size of swap with free -h. For increasing see: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-20-04
If this doesn't work, then I'm sorry, I have no other solution either.

Switching from Ubuntu LTS 24.04 to 22.04 solved the problem (without being able to explain in more details why)
